# ROS pointgrey_camera_driver crashes when I echo its topics

Tags: ros, rospy

With Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo, I cloned the pointgrey_camera_driver to catkinws/src and did catkin_make install. When I:

```
roslaunch pointgrey_camera_driver camera.launch
```

if I

```
rostopic echo /camera/image_color
```

the camera_nodelet_manager process dies. I don't know where the problem might be. This did work at one time.

I have tried using a calibration file as well as setting the launch argument "calibrated" to 0.

When the process dies this is the message:

> [camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 14845, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/mitch/.ros/log/9c7752b6-2116-11e6-a626-c03fd56e6751/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
>   log file: /home/mitch/.ros/log/9c7752b6-2116-11e6-a626-c03fd56e6751/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log

The log files are not enlightening.

Comment: did you create the calibration file ?

Comment: I have tried using a calibration file as well as setting the launch argument "calibrated" to 0.

Comment: Having exactly the same error, no solution whatsoever, damn.